# UISearchController not showing in VC

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I am implementing a collection view controller in a ViewController which has a variable that is a UISearchController, i tried initializing it thanks based on this source code https://github.com/codeWithCal/TableViewExample/blob/SearchFilter/TableViewExample/TableViewController.swift

my only issue is that the searchBar and its filter scope are not showing. Here is my code

parent type:

```
class ContactListParent:UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate
```

the variable:

```
 let search = UISearchController()
```

initializing func:

```
 func initSearchCont(){
        search.loadViewIfNeeded()
        search.searchResultsUpdater = self
        search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        search.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
        search.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        definesPresentationContext = true
        navigationItem.searchController = search
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        search.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Dogs", "Cats"]
        search.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
```

viewDidLoad cycle:

```
         super.viewDidLoad()
            
            initArr()
// INIT Below
            initSearchCont()
//
    //        search.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
            self.view.addSubview(search.view)
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            contVC = ContactVC(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            contVC?.CLV = self
            self.addChild(contVC!) //100kb
            contVC?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: bounds.height*0.2, width: bounds.width, height:  bounds.height)
            self.view.addSubview(contVC!.view)
            contVC?.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your search variable no needed here and if you are assign to navigationitem then no need add addsubview to view ok.

Here is the sample code it will show SearchBar in NavigationBar.

> Note: Make sure that you assign UINavigationController to your
> ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureSearchbar()
}

   func configureSearchbar(){
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.title = "Contacts" //Navigation Title
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }
}
```